# In mobile format divs are not showing and footer is placed above than usual

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydlzd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KPLX.png)

```css
@media(max-width=768px){

#contact-info .icons-detail{
  float: none;
  width:100%;
  display: block;
  height:250px;
  border-bottom: #444 solid 1px;
}
}
```

```html
<section id="contact-info" class="bg-dark1">
          <div class="icons-detail">
            <i class="fas fa-hotel fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Location</h2>
            <p>50 Main Street , 10th street , boston</p>
          </div>

          <div class="icons-detail">
            <i class="fas fa-phone fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Phone Number</h2>
            <p>(555) 555-5555</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="icons-detail">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Email</h2>
            <p>frontdesk@hotelbt.co</p>
          </div>
      </section>

      <div class="clr"></div>

    <footer id="main-footer">
      <p>Hotel BT &copy; 2019,All rights reserved</p>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

In mobile format divs are not showing and footer is placed above than usual.i am doing it without using flexbox or grid layout.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your media query. Put **colon (:)** instead of **equal (=)** in the media query.

```
@media(max-width: 768px){

    #contact-info .icons-detail{
      float: none;
      width:100%;
      display: block;
      height:250px;
      border-bottom: #444 solid 1px;
    }

}
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `max-width=768px` in the `@media` should be `max-width: 768px`

```
@media(max-width:768px){

  #contact-info .icons-detail{
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    height:250px;
    border-bottom: #444 solid 1px;
  }
}
```